# Connection pool for server is closed while acquiring a connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are getting a lot of errors in our Spring boot app using Spring data Neo4j, caused by this error:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Connection pool for server server-url.example.com:xxxx is closed while acquiring a connection.
```

Does anyone have an idea of where this error comes from ? Do we have to tweak the pools on the database server side or on application side ?

We are using Neo4j 4.0.11 and spring-data-neo4j 6.1.1 (in spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j 2.5.0). The connection is made with bolt protocol.

EDIT:

Here are additional infos on our configuration:

application.yml:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9080
  error.include-message: always

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      group:
        readiness:
          include: neo4j
        liveness:
          include: neo4j
logging.level:
  root: WARN
  org.springframework: INFO
  io.package.directions: INFO

spring:
  application.name: directions
  cache:
    cache-names: nodes, records
    caffeine.spec: maximumSize=1000
  config.location: classpath:/config/
  profiles.active: prod
  jmx.enabled: false
  jackson.serialization:
    FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS: false
    WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: true
    WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false

spring.neo4j:
  uri: ${NEO4J_URL}
  authentication:
    username: ${NEO4J_USERNAME}
    password: ${NEO4J_PASSWORD}

mail:
  api: "http://${MAIL_SERVICE_HOST:mail}:${MAIL_SERVICE_PORT:9000}"
```

We connect to another kubernetes pod using bolt protocol.

Here is our fairly simple transaction management bean:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TxConfig {
    final Driver driver;

    public TxConfig(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveTransactionManager reactiveTransactionManager() {
        return new ReactiveNeo4jTransactionManager(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the Spring Data Neo4j version? This is not a SDN version but something else, maybe Spring Boot?

Comment: Done, my bad it was the springboot starter version.

Comment: Thanks. This does help me to at least say it is not a (transitive) driver dependency problem. Can you give more input like where do you connect to (Docker, "Cloud", localhost?) And also interesting: Your connection setup (application.properties, custom beans)

Comment: Here you go, I added everything that I tought was relevant.

Comment: This looks ok. So I would guess its the database's configuration. Did you set the listening and advertise addresses? https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address

Comment: Here are the properties I found in the conf:
`causal_clustering.transaction_advertised_address=neo4j-prod-xxxxxxxx-xxxx:6000
causal_clustering.raft_advertised_address=neo4j-prod-xxxxxxxx-xxxx:7000
causal_clustering.discovery_advertised_address=neo4j-prod-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx:5000
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687`